# Multiple Image Upload Preview with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following `javascript` inside my `rails 5 app` in order to preview the image before the form gets submitted.

The image form field has a setup for multiple files, but the javascript has a setup for only one. I can preview more then one image but eventually only one gets uploaded.

How can I make this javascript preview and upload multiple images?

```
<script>
    function handleFileSelect(event)
    {
        console.log(event)
        var input = this;
        if (input.files && input.files[0])
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            console.log(reader)
            reader.onload = (function (e)
            {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="',e.target.result, '" title="', escape(e.name), '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('preview').insertBefore(span, null);
            });
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    //su kien thay doi hinh khac
     $('#files').change(handleFileSelect);
     //day la su kien click vao nut x để xóa ảnh
     $('#preview').on('click', '.remove_img_preview',function ()
    {
        $(this).parent('span').remove();
        $(this).val("");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please someone add answer to this, I am facing the same issue.